# VMWare (and other VMs) conflicting with host's physical network connectivity

Tags: networking, windows-8, virtual-machine, vmware, network-drive

A colleague and myself are encountering a conflict between our physical network and our virtual machine software.

I am using VMWare (Win8-64) and my colleague is using Hypervisor (Win8-64) but when their services are running we encounter the exact same problems - our network mapped drive disconnects often and host's Internet access in general is slow.

Is this a known issue that others have encountered? And are there any known solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try Wireshark to see whethere there is any other device on your network responding to ARP requests aimed at your guest VMs' IP addresses or doing other weird things?

I used to have this problem which my Netgear router would respond to ARP requests for IP addresses of VMs after the network had been idle for a period of time. It caused connection problems all the time. Eventually I implemented a workaround on my VMs so that they would ping the router every few minutes to keep the router from hijacking VMs' IP addresses.

Your problem may be caused by other issues, but a Wireshark session might give you some clues.

Comment: I haven't tried Wireshark, instead I used the workaround of switching from NAT to bridged networking ... although I'm no longer using that VM set up in order to check with Wireshark, thanks for the info.